# What would the type be of a function that switches order of arguments?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a function that simply switches the order of two arguments for any given function f like so:

```
flippingArguments f a b = f b a
```

when I check the type of flippingArguments with :t, I get the following:

```
flippingArguments :: (t -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t -> t2
```

which I don't understand. I would have predicted the following (which is wrong):

```
flippingArguments :: (t -> t1 -> t2) -> t -> t2 -> t1
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how to read type specification in Haskell? The way I understand it is that the first parentheses (t -> t1 -> t2) represents flippingArguments arguments, where t is f, t1 is a, t2 is b, and the following three t -> t2 -> t1 is flippingArguments return values where simply the order of t1 and t2 has been flipped. But this is wrong.

I am coming from Java so forgive me if I don't understand what is the return value here, its probably pretty rudimentary stuff. So to reiterate, can anyone explain to me the type notation of flippingArguments?

Comment: `flippingArguments` transforms the fuction `a -> b -> c` to the function `b -> a -> c`. The type `(t -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t -> t2` equivalent with `(t -> t1 -> t2) -> (t1 -> t -> t2)`.

Comment: `t2` is the _return_ type of the input function, not one of the arguments; it's not going to be an argument in the result function.

Answer (score 9):

The following might help:

```
flippingArguments :: (t -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t -> t2
flippingArguments    f                  a     b  = f b a
```

We have that the first argument `f` has type `(t -> t1 -> t2)`, i.e. it is a binary function taking two arguments of type `t` and `t1` and returns a value of type `t2`.

Then, the second argument `a` is of type `t1`.

Then, the third argument `b` is of type `t`.

Finally, the result of `flippingArguments f a b` is of type `t2`.

---

A more self-evident implementation might be:

```
flippingArguments :: (t -> t1 -> t2) -> (t1 -> t -> t2)
flippingArguments    f               =  \a     b -> f b a
```

Here we have that there is only a single argument `f`, with the same type as above. The result is a lambda, which takes as input `a` and `b`, and produces the intended result.

In spite of the different syntax, there's no difference between this variant and the first implementation. Indeed, thanks to *currying*, there no difference between a function taking three arguments `f,a,b` and returning a value of type `t2`, and a function taking only a single argument `f` and returning a functional value of type `t1->t->t2`.